# Нужно создать цикл

Tags: bash

Нужно подключаться по ip адресам.
Создаю цикл

```
for SERVERS in 192.168.{11..75}.{11..14};
do
echo $SERVERS
done
```

Переменная $SERVERS получает айпи адреса 192.168.11.11 192.168.11.12 192.168.11.13 192.168.11.14 192.168.12.11 И так далее. То что нужно.
А теперь сама задача. Мне нужно создать переменную чтобы при каждой итерации предыдущего цикла она получала ip адрес, к примеру.
192.168.11.11 получаем 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.12 получаем 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.13 получаем 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.14 получаем 192.168.11.1
и
192.168.12.11 получаем 192.168.12.1
и так далее.
Как мне сделать такую переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К функциям из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690695/2101808)

```
ip2int()
{
    local a b c d
    { IFS=. read a b c d; } <<< $1
    echo $(((((((a << 8) | b) << 8) | c) << 8) | d))
}

int2ip()
{
    local ui32=$1; shift
    local ip n
    for n in 1 2 3 4; do
        ip=$((ui32 & 0xff))${ip:+.}$ip
        ui32=$((ui32 >> 8))
    done
    echo $ip
}
```

добавь

```
gate()
{
    local addr=$(ip2int $1); shift
    local mask=$((0xffffffff << (32 -$1))); shift
    int2ip $(((addr & mask) + 1))
}
```

Использовать так

```
for SERVERS in 192.168.{11..75}.{11..14};
do
echo $SERVERS
GATEWAY=$(gate $SERVERS 24)
echo $GATEWAY
done
```

где 24 это маска.

Comment: Исправил. Нужно GATEWAY=$(gate $SERVERS 24)

Comment: Но получается вот так 192.168.11.11
192.168.11.1
192.168.11.12
192.168.11.0
192.168.11.13
192.168.11.1
192.168.11.14192.168.11.0

Comment: Получается он дает 1 а потом 0 потом опять 1.

Comment: исправил, скобочки

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает

Answer (score 2):

нужен цикл — так создайте:

```
for i in 192.168.{11..75}; do
  for j in {11..14}; do
    ip1=$i.$j 
    ip2=$i.1
    echo $ip1 $ip2
  done
done
```

пример вывода:

```
$ bash скрипт | head
192.168.11.11 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.12 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.13 192.168.11.1
192.168.11.14 192.168.11.1
192.168.12.11 192.168.12.1
192.168.12.12 192.168.12.1
192.168.12.13 192.168.12.1
192.168.12.14 192.168.12.1
192.168.13.11 192.168.13.1
192.168.13.12 192.168.13.1
```